# Aggregate group by response based on certain count (or size) Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am looking to create a sum based on certain values obtained after a `groupby` count (or size). I have created a mock DataFrame and the desired output bellow. It should be self explanatory from the example what I am looking for. I checked quite a bit but it seems there is no straight answer.

```
     
data = {'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C'], 'col2' :[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A','B','A','A','A','B','C','C']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

data.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col2'].count()
```

The output for this count is:

```
A     A       2
      B       2
      C       1
B     A       1
      B       3
      C       2
C     A       4
      B       2
      C       3
```

I would like to do a further calculation on this output and get:

```
A     A       2
    (B+C)     3
B   (A+C)     3
      B       3
C   (A+B)     6
      C       3
```

Comment: _"It should be self explanatory from the example what I am looking for."_ - actually, for some reason, I'm not understanding it. Will you please elaborate a bit? It looks like a cool problem, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: @richardec it seems OP wants to check if `col1` and `col2` are equal? At least that's how I interpreted it

Comment: I have two columns that contain similar values. Sometimes an A has a corresponding A in col2 other times it has a B or a C. When I do the count I get the first output (pasted above) which gives me an overview of the number of times each A has a corresponding A, a B or a C. I would like to keep the matching A to A = 'number of occurrences' intact and sum the other responses. In the end I would like to have A A = 2 and all the other values corresponding to A from col2 summed together. The same for all other variables in col1. B B = x and B (rest) = sum(rest). Where rest = A+C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create dummy columns and `groupby` using those columns:

```
out = (data
       .assign(match=data['col1']==data['col2'], count=1)
       .groupby(['col1','match'], as_index=False)
       .agg({'col2': lambda x: '+'.join(x.unique()), 'count':'sum'})
       .drop(columns='match'))
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  count
0    A  B+C      3
1    A    A      2
2    B  C+A      3
3    B    B      3
4    C  A+B      6
5    C    C      3
```